# c++ non virtual function acts like virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

Probably, i misunderstood c++ polymorphism(virtual function).
Please point me what i miss.

the source code is below

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        virtual void print(void) {
            cout<<"class A"<<endl;
        }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        void print(void) {
            cout<<"class B"<<endl;
        }
};

class C : public B {
    public:
        void print(void) {
            cout<<"class C"<<endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    A *pAa = &a;
    A *pAb = &b;
    A *pAc = &c;
    B *pBc = &c;

    pAa->print();
    pAb->print();
    pAc->print();
    pBc->print();                   // shouldn't be "class B"

    return 0;
}

result

------------------------------
class A
class B
class C
class C                             // shouldn't be "class B"
```

my understanding is that
the last print statement should print "class B"
because pBc is a pointer of class B and the print function in class B is non virtual member function. i could not find the answer about this situation.

please tell me why or point me where i can find the answer and
understand c++ polymorphism in comprehension.
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function with a given signature is declared as virtual in a top-level base class, then the function is virtual *in all derived classes* no matter if it is marked with the keyword `virtual` (`override`, `final`) or not:

> [virtual function specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)
>
> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (**whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration**)

```
struct Base {
    // Pure virtual function.
    virtual void foo() const = 0;  
};

struct A : public Base {
    // Overriding virtual function, even if it 
    // is not marked as virtual (override, or final).
    void foo() const {}   
};
```

In `A`, adding the `virtual` specifier to `foo()` would only bring *semantic* value; it will be no functional difference whether `virtual` is omitted or not (unless someone changes the interface in `Base`).

---

Many static analyzers enforce<sup>(1)</sup> marking derived virtual functions with `override` or `final`, for two reasons:

- semantics; clearly showing the given function is a virtual function (as per being defined so higher up in the inheritance chain), and
- enforcement; if a function is marked as `override` and `final` but is not actually an *overriding function*, you will get a compiler error, which can be particularly useful to protect against mistakes when changing a base class interface (whilst forgetting which classes that actually implements this interface).

E.g.:

```
struct Base {
    // Pure virtual function.
    virtual void foo() const = 0;  
};

struct A : public Base {
    // Overriding virtual function.
    void foo() const override {}   
};

struct B final : public Base {
    // Overriding (final) virtual function.
    void foo() const final {}

    // Error: Function does not override.
    // void bar() const override {}
};
```

---

<sub>(1) E.g. Rule A10-3-1 in the [Autsar C++14 Language Guidelines](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/17-03/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf) (safety-critical development in automotive) is categorized as a **required rule**: *Virtual function declaration shall contain exactly one of the three specifiers:(1) `virtual`, (2) `override`, (3) `final`.*</sub>

Comment: now i clearly understand what i miss. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> the print function in class B is non virtual member function

No. Since `A::print` is marked as `virtual` and `B` inherits from `A`, then `B::print` is [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) too; regardless of the keywork `virtual` is specified on it or not.

(emphasis mine)

> If some member function vf is declared as virtual in a class Base, and
> some class Derived, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from
> Base, has a declaration for member function with the same
>
> - name
> - parameter type list (but not the return type)
> - cv-qualifiers
> - ref-qualifiers
>
> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (**whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration**) and overrides Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).

Comment: Once virtual, always virtual. I always leave the keyword present in derived classes as a reminder. Particularly in deep inheritance trees.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter A better option (i.m.o) is to use `override` in the derived classes since it'll give you an error if it's in fact _not_ overriding when that was the purpose. With `virtual` only you may introduce a new overload when you meant to override.

Comment: now i clearly understand what i miss. Thank you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes a good point